# Is there a way to configure VlanID for Hyper-V virtual switch with command line (e.g., PowerShell) or programmatically?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'm looking a way to set VlanID of Hyper-V Virtual Switch with PowerShell, I've tried "Get-VMSwitch" but I can't find a VlanID setting.

[image: Setup w/ UI]
[image: All members of VMSwitch by PowerShell]

Answer (score -2):

Please google before asking questions
Answer is [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848475(v=wps.630).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, but your link is about setting Vlan for VM adapter, not for a VM switch, which doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I done some mistake while understanding your question but check [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/98be7790-fdcd-4a9d-8d3e-c49e4f9d0a5a/disable-virtual-switch-vlan-id?forum=winserverhyperv). That page consists of deleting the VLAN ID or use WMICode Creator and Query the " Msvm_EthernetSwitchPortVlanSettingData" Class from "root\virtualization\v2" NameSpace.  It is the place that setting will be saved.  Do your stuff for updating